# SOLR Stats on date field

Tags: solr

Im trying to get stats on DATE field but the results are failing when I retrieve using PYSOLR -

The problem is the sum field. THis date - 28129-09-01T23:59:59.999Z - does not look in the correct format and while formatting this date, I get errors.

```
<lst name="orderDate_tdt">
<date name="min">2013-08-16T00:00:00Z</date>
<date name="max">2014-08-21T00:00:00Z</date>
<long name="count">588</long>
<long name="missing">0</long>
<date name="sum">28129-09-01T23:59:59.999Z</date>
<date name="mean">2014-06-28T08:36:44.081Z</date>
<double name="sumOfSquares">-2.0737443528198062E20</double>
<double name="stddev">NaN</double>
<lst name="facets"/>
</lst>
```

Comment: it's sum of dates. what you expect here? if i plus two dates (today), i should get something in 4029 year. It looks like a correct behaviour to me. This sum field saying that sum is January 1st at 28129 year

Comment: Thanks....The culprit is python solr module..It can't format that date............raise ValueError ("'%s' is not a valid ISO 8601 Solr date" % value)
[Tue Sep 23 16:35:05 2014] [error] [client 10.172.0.10] ValueError: '28129-09-01T23:59:59.999Z' is not a valid ISO 8601 Solr date